# Ionic calling submit method in another method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Below mentioned is my submit method will post some data to the server when I click on a submit button.
it is working well when the action is performed manually. but I don't want to press submit button every time I want to call this after input texts were filled for this I'm calling this method in another method at that time it is not posting anything it is giving undefined can anyone help me on this

````
  start() {

    SMSReceive.startWatch(
      () => {
        document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', (e: any) => {

          var IncomingSMS = e.data;

          this.smsaddress = IncomingSMS.address;
          this.smsbody = IncomingSMS.body;

          if (this.smsbody.includes("HELLO") || this.smsbody.includes("HI")) {
            alert("Data : " + this.smsbody + this.smsaddress);

            const obj={
              smsbody:this.smsbody,
              smsaddress:this.smsaddress
              }
            this.submit(obj);

          } else {
            alert("resetting")
            this.resetdata();
          }
        })
      },
      () => { console.log('watch start failed') }
    )
  }

 submit(msg) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post(this.ip + "/api/route", { headers: headers }).pipe(map(res => res.json()))
      .subscribe(data => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        this.presentToast('Message has been submitted successfully', false, 'bottom');
        this.resetdata();
      })
  }; ```
````

Comment: What is the console error output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to pass data in post request

```
 submit(msg) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post(this.ip + "/api/route",msg, { headers: headers },).pipe(map(res => res.json()))
      .subscribe(data => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        this.presentToast('Message has been submitted successfully', false, 'bottom');
        this.resetdata();
      })
```